# Who was the judge in The Dark Knight Rises?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight-rises

The man "judging" (offering them the choice of exile or death) the rich and the police brought in front of him in The Dark Knight Rises looked very familiar.  Have we seen him before?

[image]

Comment: Is this a general reference question? [Meta discussion.](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2367/is-general-reference-used-inconsistently)

Comment: The answer an can be found on the [Wikipedia page for The Dark Knight Rises](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Knight_Rises): *The wealthy and powerful are dragged from their homes and given show trials, presided over by Dr. Jonathan Crane, where the "convicted" die no matter the sentence.*

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, the judge was the Scarecrow, aka Dr. Johnathon Crane (Cillian Murphy), who was also in both *Batman Begins* and *The Dark Knight*.  He wasn't explicitly introduced in *The Dark Knight Rises*.

Comment: Relevant: http://cheezcomixed.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/koma-comic-strip-inception-reunion.png

Answer (score -2):

Bane broke all of the prisoners out of blackgate prison and Jonathan crane was one of them. Then when bane was in charge of gotham, he made crane a judge.