# Where was Jonathan Crane/Scarecrow imprisoned before The Dark Knight Rises?

Tags: dc, batman, the-dark-knight-rises, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight

Jonathan Crane/Scarecrow is one of the main villains in *[Batman Begins (2005)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0372784/)*. He is captured again by Batman at the beginning of *[The Dark Knight (2008)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0372784/)*. Also:

> He [was the judge in *The Dark Knight Rises (2012)*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20886/who-was-the-judge-in-the-dark-knight-rises).

Where was he imprisoned? Arkham Asylum or Blackgate Penitentiary?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I believe he is freed from Blackgate Penitentiary. Mainly due to him being apprehended by Batman in *The Dark Knight* and then not showing up again until after Bane opens Blackgate.

Batman Wiki entry on [Jonathan Crane](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/The_Scarecrow_%28Cillian_Murphy%29#The_Dark_Knight_Rises):

> When Bane frees the prisoners from Blackgate Penitentiary, Scarecrow is one of the thousands of prisoners freed.

At the end of *Batman Begins*, the statement is made that the Narrows, [Arkham Asylum's](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Arkham_Asylum#Batman_Begins) location, was "lost", which would mean that sociopathic criminals that would have been taken to Arkham would instead be housed elsewhere, namely, Blackgate.